# String items in list: how to remove certain keywords?

Tags: string, python-2.7, get, web-scraping, strip

I have a set of links that looks like the following:

```
links = ['http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/1',
'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/2',
'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/3',...]
```

I want to extract the `1`, `2`, `3`, and so on from this list, and store the extracted data in `subcategory_explicit`. They're stored as `str`, and I'm having trouble getting at them with the following code:

```
subcategory_explicit = [cat.get('subcategory') for cat in links if cat.get('subcategory') is not None]
```

Do I have to change my data type from `str` to something else? What would be a better way to obtain and store the extracted values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subcategory_explicit = [i[i.find('subcategory'):] for i in links if 'subcategory' in i]`

This uses a substring via slicing, starting at the "s" in "subcategory" until the end of the string. By adding `len('subcategory')` to the value from `find`, you can exclude "subcategory" and get "/#" (where # is whatever number).

Comment: How does this work for `subcategory` values with more than one digit? I'm running it now and, for `subcategory` values like `10`, `11`, and `12`, it stores `1`,`1`,`1`.

Comment: It seemed to work for me. This was the code: `[i[i.find('subcategory') + len('subcategory'):] for i in links]`. I put in some 2 digit values and got them correctly. The `:` is important!

Comment: Yeah, that `:` was what I forgot. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using re module):

```
import re

links = [
    'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/1',
    'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/2',
    'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/3']

d = "|".join(links)
# 'http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/1|http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/2|http://www.website.com/category/subcategory/3'

pattern = re.compile("/category/(?P<category_name>\w+)/\d+", re.I)
subcategory_explicit = pattern.findall(d)

print(subcategory_explicit)
```